# dynamic dropdowns

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i want three dropdowns. The second and third dropdowns need to be dynamically populated by the
previous selections. I believe this can be done with ajax & php querying my database.The three
dropdowns are puuling data from three different columns in one table.
An example would be something like this...
http://www.kbb.com/used-cars#

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get this accomplished?

Any help is MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Here : http://php-ajax-code.blogspot.com/2007/07/ajax-triple-dropdown-with-states-cities.html
 :)

Comment: thanks for the link... I'm trying to make sense of it (not much luck so far)

Comment: Have you been successful with this example? I feel I comprehend most of the script except:
    $data=$_GET['data'];
     $val=$_GET['val'];

Comment: $data=$_GET['data']; and $val=$_GET['val'];  Just get the parameters sent to "the url" here : req.open("GET", "locale.php?data="+src+"&val="+val);  What exactly you didn't understand ? You know what is $_GET in php? Good luck

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

three select fields

**JavaScript:**

use jQuery or some other framework. Then bind "onchange" event for given select field to some javascript function, which makes AJAX request to the php script and sends the selected value.

**PHP:**

read the value, make the decision and return results. Result can be either HTML or JSON, depends what you really need.

When Javascript gets the results from the given PHP script, you should provide the callback function, which populates the other two fields based on returned value.